# Who first created or popularized the original XMLHTTPRequest / MSXML?

Tags: javascript, history, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to understand the origins of AJAX, and think MSXML and XMLHTTPRequest were the objects that started it all.

Which came first, and/or became the defacto way to create dynamic pages?

Comment: [Web 2.0](http://www.paulgraham.com/web20.html), [Ajax a new approach to web dev](http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications), [XMLHTTP](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20358)

Comment: [MSDN XMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950766.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the origins, see Wikipedia's [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) article, particularly this excerpt:

> The concept behind the XMLHttpRequest object **was originally created by
>   the developers of Outlook Web Access (by Microsoft) for Microsoft
>   Exchange Server 2000**. An interface called IXMLHTTPRequest was
>   developed and implemented into the second version of the MSXML library
>   using this concept. The second version of the MSXML library was
>   shipped with Internet Explorer 5.0 in March 1999, allowing access, via
>   ActiveX, to the IXMLHTTPRequest interface using the XMLHTTP wrapper of
>   the MSXML library.

As for the first massive usage, the Wikipedia article on [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) has the answer:

> The utility of background HTTP requests to the server and asynchronous
>   web technologies remained fairly obscure until it started appearing in
>   full scale online applications such as **Outlook Web Access** (2000) and
>   **Oddpost** (2002), and later, Google made a wide deployment of Ajax with
>   **Gmail** (2004) and **Google Maps** (2005).

I am sure there are other examples, but personally the example of Gmail strikes home.
I never used Outlook Web Access, but I clearly remember the first time I gained access to my Gmail mailbox. At that time I really was wondering how they achieved that without iframes...